# Click button with Selenium Python works only with debug mode

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, webdriverwait

I tried to get data from the menu in this [website](https://re.jrc.ec.europa.eu/pvg_tools/en/). I've written this script which seems work well in debug mode. In this script, i close the chrome every time I've get information for certain city.

In debug mode, the detail information is shown when 'element' is clicked by the script. However, if i run the script, it seems that it doesn't do anything after city information is sent. The button 'Visualize Results' is enabled in the website when city data is entered, but the detail information that supposed to be shown after clicking this button by the script is not shown as if it is not clicked. Is there something that i miss?

thank you in advance.

```py
for city in Cities:
    chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()   
    chrome_options.add_experimental_option('prefs', prefs)
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options)
    driver.get(link)            
    driver.find_element(By.ID, "inputText").send_keys(city)    
    driver.find_element(By.ID, 'btninputText').click()
    element = wait(driver, 5).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH,div[@id="btviewPVGridGraph"]'))).click()
    driver.close()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You need to wait for clickability of all 3 elements you accessing here. Presence is not enough.
2. Need to add a short delay between clicking the search button and clicking visualization button

The following code works:

```py
import time

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

options = Options()
options.add_argument("start-maximized")

webdriver_service = Service('C:\webdrivers\chromedriver.exe')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, service=webdriver_service)
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 30)

url = "https://re.jrc.ec.europa.eu/pvg_tools/en/"
driver.get(url)

wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "inputText"))).send_keys("Paris")
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "btninputText"))).click()
time.sleep(2)
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "btviewPVGridGraph"))).click()
```

Th result is:

[image]

Comment: Hallo Prophet..thank you for your addition. Adding a short delay help the problem..

Answer (score 0):

Try below xpath

```
wait(driver, 5).until(EC.presence_of_element_located(By.XPATH,'//div[@id="btviewPVGridGraph"]')).click()
```